# Algebra solve for $x$ in the equation $x^3 = x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried to solve for x in the equation $x^3=x$. I did

$$x^3=x$$

$$x^2=1$$

$$x=\pm1$$

but it's wrong, can anyone help.

Comment: try the solution  0.

Comment: You can't divide by $x$ if $x=0$. Hence, you must consider the possibility that $x=0$ independently. And it turns out that $x=0$ also works, so that should give you an answer.

Comment: You have two thirds of it but you forgot a very important and critical step.  If $x = 0$ you can not do step two.  So you must consider Case 1: x = 0 then x^3 = x = 0 is acceptable.  Case 2: x \ne 0.  then x = +/- 1.  So x = 0,1,-1.  *THREE* possible answers.

Comment: If $x^3 = -x$ then $x = i = \sqrt {-1}$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot $0$. You shouldn't divide by $x$, or else you will miss it. You can solve it like this:

$$x^3=x$$ subtract $x$ from both sides$$x^3-x=0$$ factor out $x$ $$x(x^2-1)=0$$factor $x^2-1$ $$x(x+1)(x-1)=0$$ Simplify $$x=-1,0,1$$

Comment: That's nice.  It avoids the case breaking divide by zero| x is 0 which is so hard to explain without confusing people.

Comment: This is clear and helpful, I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial $p(x) = x^3 - x$ has at most *three* zeroes by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. By inspection, $1, -1, 0$ are three zeroes of $p$:
$$
p(1) = 1^3 - 1 = 0 \\
p(-1) = (-1)^3 - (-1) = -1 + 1 = 0 \\
p(0) = 0^3 - 0 = 0,
$$
and by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, these are the only zeroes of $p$.

Comment: Do you want to say a bit more about how you find those zeros?

Comment: I don't think it is evident for the OP.

Comment: @Thomas Maybe you should consider that the other answer to this question already showed a method of computing the zeroes. The OP may also benefit from seeing someone point out that in certain cases, we don't need to do any hard work if we spend a few extra moments pondering the nature of the problem and other facts we already know. The point of downvoting someone's answer is to send the message that the answer is not useful. In light of others' answers, my answer would be truly useless if I just computed the zeroes like the other answer.